# Properties in awful.spawn make no change

Tags: awesome-wm

Awesome v4.3. Trying to launch something in rc.lua.

```lua
    awful.spawn("xterm", {
        border_width = 0,
        titlebars_enabled = false,
        tag = "2",
        placement = awful.placement.bottom_right,
    })
```

xterm spawns, but the listed propertis make no effect on the xterm window.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xterm` doesn't support the startup notification protocol needed for this to work. Please consider `rxvt-unicode` (often called `urxvt`) as a drop-in replacement. It is often faster than xterm and has more features.

If you really want `xterm`, the `client.startup_id` documentation provides a workaround to force applications that don't support startup notification to work anyway. In some case, this patch can make the problem worst so it cannot be applied by default. Using applications that comply with the protocol should always be the first choice.

(note to other people reading this in the future: Please consider upgrading to awesome 4.3 or newer. AwesomeWM 4.0-4.2 has a bug regarding this feature and the execution order of the property can clash with the one provided by the `awful.rules`)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Thank you very much! The fun thing is, that I tried xclock to check if that was an xtem issue.

Comment: All original "x*something*" applications predate that protocol. Some other applications like Firefox and Chrome support it, but their implementation have bugs and end up not working. Finally some recent version of Qt regressed and it no longer works. So it is a hit and miss game. Some application will work (all GTK application, KDE3, KDE4, Qt4, wxwidgets) and other wont.